# Spring Application gets 404 error on TomCat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, model-view-controller

how are u?

I'm doing a Spring Boot Application and i'm getting the 404 error on TomCat. I'm using Maven to build the .WAR file and do the deploy to TomCat with the tomcat7-maven-plugin. I already read a lot of topics with a context very similar to mine but i cant find a solution.
Something that i notice, is that when i do the deploy, the Spring Letters not show anymore on TomCat prompt.

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/scim/] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.64
```

[Print of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVdoB.png)

Some dudes try to resolve this putting `extends SpringBootServletInitializer` and the

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder){
    return builder.sources(ScimApplication.class);
}
```

on the main class, but i already did that, and didn't worked.

I used to compile the .war file with the `mvn clean install` command, then i do the `mvn clean tomcat7:deploy` to do the deploy directly to the TomCat, that i already configurated the user on tomcat-users.xml, and add the server tag on the settings.xml on conf folder of Maven.

Even if i enter on the TomCat's manager page, and do the deploy from there, when i try localhost:8080/scim, i get 404 error.

I will put my initialization TomCat log here, as well my Controller, POM.xml and Main class.

Thank you and if you guys need more information, just tell me.

*TomCat Log Initialization*

```
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.64
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 2 2022 19:08:46 UTC
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.64.0
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_333
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_333-b02
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\conf\logging.properties
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=\apache-tomcat-9.0.64
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=\apache-tomcat-9.0.64
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\temp
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.811 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.33] using APR version [1.7.0].
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.811 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.827 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
07-Jul-2022 11:09:14.827 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022]
07-Jul-2022 11:09:15.215 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Jul-2022 11:09:15.265 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [710] milliseconds
07-Jul-2022 11:09:15.297 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
07-Jul-2022 11:09:15.297 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.64]
07-Jul-2022 11:09:15.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\scim.war]
07-Jul-2022 11:09:19.655 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.057 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [269] milliseconds.
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.075 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\scim.war] has finished in [4,747] ms
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.075 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\docs]
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.127 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\docs] has finished in [52] ms
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.127 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\examples]
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.684 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\examples] has finished in [557] ms
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.684 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\host-manager]
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.757 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [72] ms
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.757 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\manager]
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.794 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\manager] has finished in [37] ms
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.794 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\ROOT]
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.849 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.64\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [55] ms
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.849 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Jul-2022 11:09:20.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [5601] milliseconds
```

*POM.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ushin</groupId>
    <artifactId>scim</artifactId>
    <name>scim</name>
    <description>scim</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--Spring-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--MySQL-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>scim</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <executable>C:\Users\gbrasolin\.jdks\corretto-11.0.15\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                        <server>scim</server>
                        <path>/scim</path>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

*Controller*

```
package com.ushin.scim.controllers;

import com.ushin.scim.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/Users")
public class UserController {

    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map createUser(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload, HttpServletResponse response){
        return userService.createUser(payload, response);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Map getUsers(@RequestParam Map<String, String> payload) throws IOException {
        return userService.getUsers(payload);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody Map getSingleUser (@PathVariable String id,  HttpServletResponse response){
        return userService.getSingleUser(id, response);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody Map updateUser(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload, @PathVariable String id){
        return userService.updateUser(payload, id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH, value = "/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody Map disableUser (@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload, @PathVariable String id){
        return userService.disableUser(payload, id);
    }

}
```

*Main Class*

```
package com.ushin.scim;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ScimApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ScimApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder){
        return builder.sources(ScimApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question.  You're getting a 404 trying to access the endpoint `/scim`.  In your controller there are no mappings for `/scim`.  What have you added to your code that makes you believe this endpoint should exist?  Assuming `/scim` is the context path, nothing listens on this, try `/scim/Users` maybe?

Comment: Well, when i try to run the application on Intellij with the spring boot server, the mappings work well. Using postman i can do all the requests and stuff, but when i do the deploy to tomcat, at least according to what i was reading about, the path after the localhost:8080/ is the name of the war file. My war file name is scim.war, so thats why im trying to reach localhost:8080/scim. For the first time that i've tried, it works. It brings the same whiteblank page of spring. After some deploys it stop worked and i dont changed anything. I cant see right now reasons for not work, based on files.

Comment: What's the final structure of the deployed war?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the JRE_HOME (was running java 8) to the same path of JAVA_HOME which is with Java 11, and it worked. Tomcat was on Java 8 and my project was running Java 11.

Log:
`Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_333"`

My POM.xml:
`<java.version>11</java.version>`